# Cloudflare CDN header cf-cache-status:MISS when loading image from page

Tags: javascript, caching, http-headers, cloudflare

I'm trying to load images from Amazon S3 thru Cloudflare CDN. When adding `src` to `<img />` tag by JavaScript response header `cf-cache-status` returns `MISS`, but when i'm opening picture in new tab it's `HIT` as it should be (working thru CDN cache).

The difference in request headers is

when getting image by JavaScript:

```
accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
referer:https://example.com/
```

when open in new tab:

```
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
cache-control:max-age=0
if-modified-since:Sun, 15 Jan 2017 15:57:40 GMT
if-none-match:"62d2f51d08bd490d403206a37bec9c15"
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
```

What should i do to make it `HIT` from my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

try to make your header respond to be

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000, s-max-age=2592000";
```